# IOS UIButton's size gets bigger when touch inside

Tags: ios, uibutton

simple codes..

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)dragout:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)dragout:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"-----");
}
@end
```

and in Storyboard, there is 1 button which size is fit in text "button". Link 'sent event:touch drag outside" to "dragout" IBAction.

When I touch button inside and drag my finger to outside of button, i need move more than button size to call "dragout" IBAction. Nearly 3x width&height size. Why is this happens? Thx for read.

Comment: Very interesting! The same rule apparently applies to UIControl. My speculation is that this is done for UI reasons, because peoples fingers can sometimes move around a lot on the screen compared to a mouse pointer. If you want different behavior you'll have to subclass UIControl and override its touch tracking methods.

Comment: @Dan_Gabicoware Im newbie in IOS. I tried to find it some sites. But samples doesnt work and I cant find subclass UIControl & override it. Is there any site to see & learn that? plus...What is the name of that  function(touch area bigger than original one)?